# Robocode + Python

Tags: python, jython, robocode

The question is, how do you make a robot for Robocode using Python? There seem to be two options:

- Robocode + Jython
- Robocode for .NET + Iron Python

There's some info for the first, but it doesn't look very robust, and none for the latter. Step by step, anyone?

Comment: I have tried posting a question at StackOverflow. Also I installed Jython 2.2, the last version with jythonc, and tried compiling a simple robot to .class and to .jar. It worked as far as producing these files, but Robocode doesn't seem to recognize them as robot, even though I put them in robots/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your java-class extends `robocode.Robot` everything is recognized as robot.

It doesn't matter where you put the class.