# Is threre a RoboCode like Game or Challenge for Python?

Tags: python, robocode

Im looking for a game or challenge which is similar to [RoboCode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) or [Scalatron](http://scalatron.github.com/). I am not interested in challenges like [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) where i get points for solving a specific problem. I am looking for the direct competition. I am aware of http://sumost.ca/steve/games/ but sadly there are no python based projects. If you have any recommendations please share them with me.

Comment: RoboCode has .NET support you could always write in IronPython?

Answer (score 5):

And what about aichallenge?

Sponsored by Google, the type of competition that you search for, and loads of languages available.
They provide a sample application that works, and you have to increase your ant's intelligence by yourself.

http://aichallenge.org/

Provided you post, I think you'll love it :)

BTW, **[found this](http://coding.scribd.com/2012/05/24/compete-against-our-developers/)** on [Hacker news](http://news.ycombinator.com/) yesterday

Why not play, code and find a job at the same time ^^

Answer (score 1):

Scalatron has a RESTFUL Web API https://github.com/scalatron/scalatron/blob/master/Scalatron/doc/markdown/Scalatron%20APIs.md#scalatron-restful-web-api

This means you could play using Python over the API.

I am also interested in this kind of game and have considered creating my own. I would rather let players play over a RESTFUL API to allow flexibility of playing with whatever language they choose.

As for using IronPython it seems this user had no luck: [Robocode + Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683501/robocode-python)